# Word for someone who has experienced the hardships of life too young

Tags: idiom-requests

What is a word for someone concerned when they should be innocent or oblivious to hardships? I.e. a child worrying about money or when their next meal is.

Answer (score 1):

One idiomatic expression that is sometimes used for the phenomenon you ask about is that the person **missed out on childhood**. The earliest Google Books match for this phrase is fairly recent ([1979](https://books.google.com/books?id=NwwdAQAAMAAJ&q=%22missed+out+on+childhood%22&dq=%22missed+out+on+childhood%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU3tnl0q_SAhWps1QKHZOoCNEQ6AEIHDAA)), but the expression has subsequently generated enough matches to [generate an Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=missed+out+on+childhood&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmissed%20out%20on%20childhood%3B%2Cc0), and a [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22missed%20out%20on%20childhood%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) for the phrase yields 30 unique matches from 1979 forward.

The expression sometimes comes up in connection with child celebrities, as in this exchange from "[Modelling's Just Fun for 12-year-old Brooke](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/59834228?searchTerm=%22missed+out+on+childhood%22)," in *The Australian Women's Weekly* (November 9, 1977):

> I asked Brooke [Shields] if she sometimes felt as though she'd **missed out on childhood**.
>
> "Nope," she answered. "I've had a great childhood — friends and fun and stuff."

But it can also apply to people who missed out on a carefree youth as a result of family- or society-related turmoil and privation, as in Neerosh Mudaly & ‎Christopher Goddard, [*The Truth is Longer Than a Lie: Children's Experiences of Abuse and Professional Interventions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GeYPBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22missed+out+on+childhood%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4_bK806_SAhVKj1QKHe54DE0Q6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22missed%20out%20on%20childhood%22&f=false) (2006):

> Eliza found various ways to cope with the confusions of her life [trapped in an abusive family]:
>
> > Yeah, I have a habit of blocking things out. I think I'm an expert at that. ... Sort of maybe it was born in me... {I also} turned to ways of denying all the pain and the issues and whatever. I went through a stage with drinking and the drugs and that didn't particularly help. I was a great one for the old self-mutilation as well.
> >
> > I think what happens with most kids, is they grow up so quick, I had to grow up too quickly and I just feel like I **missed out on childhood** pretty much. Which is a pretty huge thing to cope with. Yeah, at times I still feel like I'm sort of stuck there, back in childhood. I didn't really have a choice, you have to grow up pretty fast in that sort of situation, otherwise you don't survive. It's as simple as that.